# Generate an HSV image from an `M` by `N` by 3 array in Julia

Tags: image, julia

I have an `M` by `N` by 3 array of floating-point reals which I would like to interpret as the HSV channels of an image. I would like to generate and export the image.

According to the function documentation,

> ```
> colorim(A, [colorspace])
> ```
>
> Creates a 2d color image from an AbstractArray, auto-detecting which
>   of the first or last dimension encodes the color and choosing between
>   "horizontal-" and "vertical-major" accordingly. colorspace defaults to
>   "RGB" but could also be e.g. "Lab" or "HSV".

I first tested the RGB case:

```
using Images
imwrite(colorim(rand(Float64, 200, 200, 3), "RGB"), "Image.PNG")
```

which produces the following:

[image]

However, when I replace "RGB" with "HSV" as per the documentation, I get an error message.

What is the correct syntax to interpret and export an array as HSV data?

Answer (score 5):

```
using Images, Color
B = permutedims(A, [3,1,2])  # put color first
C = reinterpret(HSV{Float64}, B)
```

Comment: Thanks for posting! Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work when it gets to the export step. Executing `B = rand(Float64, 3, 200, 200); C = reinterpret(HSV{Float64}, B); imwrite(C, "Image.PNG")` gives error messages. If you knew a workaround to export HSV images, that would be awesome.

Answer (score 2):

Tim Holy gave part of the answer, namely that the data must first be converted into an `Array{HSV{Float64}, 2}` using `reinterpret`. The missing piece is that `imwrite` does not appear to play nicely with arrays with `HSV` elements, and conversion into an `Array{RGB{Float64}, 2}` is necessary using `convert`, as Tim pointed out in [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/julia-users/L0bVECupvOQ).

Putting this all together:

```
A = ones(Float64, 3, 200, 200);
A[1, :, :] = 180.0;
B = reinterpret(HSV{Float64}, A);
C = convert(Array{RGB{Float64}}, B);
imwrite(C, "test.png")
```

giving

[image]